# hfill for 2. row of itemize

Tags: tcolorbox

i want to character(x x x) or (y y y) or (z z z) that always located in position of Ending of 2.rows.
i used \hfill but it don't work.
My Example working code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
]

\posterbox[colframe=red,width=4cm,height=4cm]{column=1}{
 \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em]
    \item a2 \\ \hfill \textcolor{blue}{x x x}%

    \item b2\\ 
    \hfill \textcolor{red}{y y y}%

    \item cccc2  ccccc cccc ccc \\ \hfill \textcolor{green}{z z z}%
\end{itemize}
}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

Please see image
Thank in advance
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `\\` to produce a line break in this case. Use a blank line instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
]

\posterbox[colframe=red,width=4cm,height=4cm]{column=1}{
 \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em]
    \item a2 

    \hfill \textcolor{blue}{x x x}%

    \item b2

    \hfill \textcolor{red}{y y y}%

    \item c2 

    \hfill \textcolor{green}{z z z}%
\end{itemize}
}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To make the text *always* in the 2nd line, I think we should employ Ti*k*Z for this. In fact, this is something like nesting Ti*k*Z pictures, which should not be done, but this is obligatory. We will nest Ti*k*Z pictures carefully.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
]

\posterbox[colframe=red,width=4cm,height=4cm]{column=1}{
 \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em]
    \item \tikz[baseline={(x.base)}] {
        \node[text width=\linewidth,%draw,
              inner sep=0pt,
              text depth=\baselineskip,
              align=justify] (x) {a1};
        \node[inner sep=0pt,
              anchor=base east,
              font=\color{blue}] at (x.south east) {x x x};
    }
    \item \tikz[baseline={(x.base)}] {
        \node[text width=\linewidth,
              inner sep=0pt,
              text depth=\baselineskip,
              align=justify] (x) {This will break to two lines};
        \node[inner sep=0pt,
              anchor=base east,
              font=\color{red}] at (x.south east) {x x x};
    }
    \item \tikz[baseline={(x.base)}] {
        \node[text width=\linewidth,
              inner sep=0pt,
              text depth=\baselineskip,
              align=justify] (x) {cccc2  ccccc cccc ccc};
        \node[inner sep=0pt,
              anchor=base east,
              font=\color{green}] at (x.south east) {x x x};
    }
\end{itemize}
}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you find it too long, maybe you should define a macro. Note that this *won't* work well with 3 lines of text or more. If you have 3 lines, you have to use `text depth=2\baselineskip` instead of `text depth=\baselineskip`.

Comment: Thank you. Please help if text is longer then xxx , yyy, zzz move to 3.row. I need that they always in ending of 2. row. Thanks

Comment: @latexforti See my edited answer

Comment: thank for good solution. But i use a2,b2,c2 as variable and sometimes long, and sometimes short. Example: In Box M is c2 short but In Box N is c2 longer...Do you have other solution for my case?

Comment: @latexforti So what if those variables go to the third line? I strongly think that manually adjusting is the best option here

Comment: Thank for good question. I will limit of total charaters of variable. Sure each item put in 2 lines

Comment: fast 99% what i need. Please set 2.line move to left that can add more characters. https://imgur.com/5t3Bk3Q : Please see image link . Thank you

Comment: @latexforti Reset your `leftmargin` option of `itemize` to `0pt` for example.

Comment: i have added: " \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0] ..." but 2. line of each item not move to left. :(

Comment: @latexforti No need to upvote all of my comments. Do the 2nd lines really do that? I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl0NL.png, which may be what you want

Comment: please see image, that i want https://imgur.com/wZsmUOd thanks

Comment: Then do not use `itemize` at all. Just use a normal `$\bullet$` in front of every text. `itemize` is supposed to align the second line with the first line

Answer (score 1):

Place an empty `\mbox{}` prior to each `\hfill`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
]

\posterbox[colframe=red,width=4cm,height=4cm]{column=1}{
 \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em]
    \item a2 \\ \mbox{}\hfill \textcolor{blue}{x x x}%

    \item b2\\ 
    \mbox{}\hfill \textcolor{red}{y y y}%

    \item c2 \\ \mbox{}\hfill \textcolor{green}{z z z}%
\end{itemize}
}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: B Segletes thank for your answer. If text is longer, example "cccc cccc   cccc ", then  zzz located in 3. row, not 2.row

Comment: @latexforti Well, if you want it to be on the 3rd line, why do you need line breaks then?

Comment: @JouleV i want it display in 2.rows (3.rows = wrong). Each item split 2 rows.