# hfill of 3. row of itemize enviroment

Tags: itemize

Continues with topic:
[hfill for 2. row of itemize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489574/hfill-for-2-row-of-itemize)

Now i want 3rd rows instead 2nd rows:
character(x1 x1 x1 x1) or (x2 x2 x2 x2) or (x3 x3 x3 x3) that always located in position of Ending of 3.rows.

Ex:

item 1: a1 a1 a1

2. row
3. row   x1 x1 x1 x1

item 2: a2 a2 a2

a2 a2 a2

a2  a2  x2 x2 x2 x2

item 3: a3 a3 a3

a3 a3 a3    x3 x3 x3 x3

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
]

\posterbox[colframe=red,width=4cm,height=4cm]{column=1}{
 \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em]
    \item \tikz[baseline={(x.base)}] {
        \node[text width=\linewidth,%draw,
              inner sep=0pt,
              text depth=\baselineskip,
              align=justify] (x) {a1};
        \node[inner sep=0pt,
              anchor=base east,
              font=\color{blue}] at (x.south east) {x x x};
    }
    \item \tikz[baseline={(x.base)}] {
        \node[text width=\linewidth,
              inner sep=0pt,
              text depth=\baselineskip,
              align=justify] (x) {This will break to three lines};
        \node[inner sep=0pt,
              anchor=base east,
              font=\color{red}] at (x.south east) {x x x};
    }
    \item \tikz[baseline={(x.base)}] {
        \node[text width=\linewidth,
              inner sep=0pt,
              text depth=\baselineskip,
              align=justify] (x) {cccc2  ccccc cccc ccc};
        \node[inner sep=0pt,
              anchor=base east,
              font=\color{green}] at (x.south east) {x x x};
    }
\end{itemize}
}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
Thank you

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but I have some difficulty understanding the precise constraints of the exercise, sorry. For instance, the kind of input and what should happen if there isn't enough material to fill two full lines (plus a word, or what?).

Comment: @frougon thank, i just add more description and example. Thanks

Comment: Am I right if I say that you want the node width to adapt in order to always produce three lines in each item? How can this be satisfied for several items at the same time, sharing  a common `\linewidth`?

Comment: @frougon i use node as guide of The old JouleV and that help display my output.

Comment: [Crosspost on LaTeX.org](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=109543#p109543)